# Why does during Make Build with Dockerfile "conda install -c conda-forge r-base" keeps failing with initial solve?

Tags: python, r, docker, conda

I'm trying to use make build which has a docker build but every time it reaches a layer in which it tries to install "conda install -c conda-forge r-base" it keeps failing:

```
Step 12/25 : RUN conda install -c conda-forge r-base
 ---> Running in 828e7f234ed3
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

And then it starts examining conflicts until it reaches this error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c conda install -c conda-forge r-base' returned a non-zero code: 1
make: *** [Makefile:2: build] Error 1
```

Does somebody have any idea what I could do to fix this? So that it continues building with no errors? I didn't code the Dockerfile so I'm a little lost on what to do.

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

ENV INSTALL_PATH /environment_name
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

#COPY environment.yml environment.yml
#RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
RUN conda create -n environment_name 
RUN /opt/conda/bin/activate environment_name
#RUN conda config --add channels conda-forge
#RUN conda config --set channel_priority strict
#RUN conda install r-cairodevice
RUN conda install -n environment_name bokeh h5py numpy scipy pandas scikit-learn sphinx spyder jupyter statsmodels
RUN conda install -n environment_name -c bioconda pymzml
RUN conda install -n environment_name -c bioconda netcdf4
RUN conda install -c conda-forge fonts-conda-forge
RUN conda install -c conda-forge r-base
RUN conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-ropls
RUN pip install flask werkzeug gunicorn 
RUN conda install seaborn
RUN echo "source activate environment_name" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/environment_name/bin:$PATH

COPY . .

RUN chmod +x run_server.sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh
ADD start.sh /
CMD /start.sh
RUN conda install -c conda-forge libjpeg-turbo
RUN git clone https://bitbucket.org/iAnalytica/mshub_process.git
RUN conda install -n environment_name -c bioconda pyteomics
#CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile - "api.app:app"
```

Makefile

```
build:
        docker build -t environment_name .
```

Comment: What else is already in the environment? Generally, better practice is to define the entire environment with a single YAML file, then create it in one go (`conda env create`), rather than with a series of `conda install` commands.

Comment: Don't mix R and Python in the same environment.

Comment: Thanks merv for the comments, I didn't write this dockerfile but I need both R and Python because of the app I am trying to work on. I know you've already given me some suggestions but could you perhaps give an example on how you would code it?

Answer (score 1):

This means that the dependencies you're listing within your conda file are causing some sort of error during the build. It could be many things, but if you were able to build that conda environment in your local environment outside of docker, then a possible culprit would be that the difference in operating system is creating a sufficient change in the dependencies that's causing the conda build to fail. Without knowing more about the error itself or the traceback, I would try commenting out half of the dependencies in your conda file and rerunning. If it succeeds, then try with the other half commented out. If it fails, uncomment half of the previously commented dependencies and continue this binary-like search until you find the offending dependency(ies).

For what it's worth, using docker removes much of the benefit of using an environment manager like conda. While I don't have visibility into the rest of your application, it might be worth considering what you're really getting out of conda in a containerized environment and determining if other means of setting up your environment better suit your needs. I say this especially because the build times for conda can be quite slow and add to the bloat of the container.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jamie! Could you perhaps help me in more detail if I post the Dockerfile here? It wasn't me that actually wrote it but I need it to continue contributing developing an app, It's been quite tricky.

Comment: Best to either post a more detailed stack overflow question that's reproducible or update your original post

Comment: I updated the post with the dockerfile and makefile, I'd really appreciate the help. I'm not sure if it'll turn out to be useful. I'm still quite confused when dealing with docker/dockefiles.